# intellij angular template creating Failed to load resource error

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea

I cannot figure out why the template intellij creates for me produces all these error. Even better the angular is not working. I cut and pasted some simple angular code from online sources to test it and put the Angular script inside index.html with no luck.

Here is my current code:

```
   <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/clickablecontroller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-controller="clickable">

    <input type="button" value="Click Me" ng-click="clickMe()">
      {{clickable.click}}

  </div>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

      <button ng-click="count = count + 1">Click me!</button>

      <p>{{ count }}</p>

  </div>
  <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.count = 0;
      });
  </script>
```

Controller: (clickablecontroller.js)

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('clickable',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.clickMe = function(){
            $scope.click = click++;
        }
    }]);
```

Errors:

[image: Errors]

Comment: Seems like `clickablecontroller` should be there after angularjs file..

Comment: You seem to rely on bower to install your JavaScript dependencies. Have you installed and configured bower? run bower install? Cutting and pasting code without understanding it is not a good strategy. Try to understand how angular works, by following a tutorial, and do all steps by yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet I am not just cut and pasting without know what it is doing. I just did that to confirm the issue was not a code mistake on my part. The code post I created. I have install bower via "npm install -g bower"

Comment: @PankajParkar I moved <script src="components/controllers/clickablecontroller.js"></script> to the <head>

Comment: And have you created a bower project, in the right directory. Have you installed the right bower packages?

Comment: I had to enable node.js and npm under settings|framework. Then type in npm restart in the terminal and it worked. Angular code is not working but all the other errors have disappeared.